# How can I use MediaRecorder API of browser in react native

Tags: react-native, mediarecorder, mediastream, web-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I just want to use media recorder API to record the stream which I'm using in WebRtc for react-native. Actually I want to save the stream to a file on the backend server. and hence i need to send the data of buffers through the sockets once the media recorder's  function (ondataavailable) is available. I've implemented it in the Web (using React.js)
This is the code I'm using to send the recorded chunks to the backend server

```
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(_stream.current, recorderOptions);
   
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
      
      if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        socket.emit("message1", event.data);
      }
    };
```

Or any other solution would be highly recommended. Thanks

Comment: hey there, i ran into the same problem, did you find any solutions?